# Python. Списки Кортеж Массивы

Tags: python, массивы, list, arraylist, хранение-данных

```
pro13 = [pricer = 11000, name = 'pro13']
pro11 =  [pricer = 10000, name = 'pro11']
pro10 =  [pricer = 9000, name = 'pro10']
pro8 =  [pricer = 8000, name = 'pro8']
pro7 =  [pricer = 4000, name = 'pro7']


value = [ pro13, pro11, pro10, pro8, pro7]
for i in range(len(value)):
    print(value[i])
```

Здраствуйте как я могу  реализовать эту конструкцию, хочу чтоб без бд было и хранить увждую переменную в массиве и чтобы цикл этот каждый раз подставлял в переменные индекс значения или название
пожалуйста помогите

Comment: `[pricer = 4000, name = 'pro7']` -> `{'pricer': 4000, 'name': 'pro7'}`

Comment: Изучите лучше классы и сделайте нормально - классы с полями, а не непонятно что.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте для хранения таких данных словари -> и делайте *индексацию* по **ключам**:

```
pro13 = {'pricer' : 11000, 'name' : 'pro13'}
pro11 = {'pricer' : 10000, 'name' : 'pro11'}
pro10 = {'pricer' : 9000, 'name' : 'pro10'}
pro8 =  {'pricer' : 8000, 'name' : 'pro8'}
pro7 =  {'pricer' : 4000, 'name' : 'pro7'}


value = [ pro13, pro11, pro10, pro8, pro7]
for k in range(len(value)):
    print(value[k])
```

Вариант 2:

```
class SData:
    def __init__(self,**kw):
        for k in kw.keys():
            setattr(self,k,kw[k])
    def __str__(self):
        res=''
        for a in self.__dict__:
            res+=f'{a} = {getattr(self,a)}\n'
        return res
pro13 = SData(pricer = 11000, name = 'pro13')
pro11 =  SData(pricer = 10000, name = 'pro11')
pro10 =  SData(pricer = 9000, name = 'pro10')
pro8 =  SData(pricer = 8000, name = 'pro8')
pro7 =  SData(pricer = 4000, name = 'pro7')
value = [ pro13, pro11, pro10, pro8, pro7]
for i in range(len(value)):
    print(value[i])
```

Comment: минус мой. Во всех переменных `pro` у вас будет SyntaxError а в цикле for вы пытаетесь вызвать метод которого нету у списка, также вы используете переменную `i` которой не существует

Comment: @Danis, я все исправил